# GridView Sorting without AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, .net-3.5

I'm trying to enable sorting for my gridview without AJAX, and having difficulty because when I call sorting it is running PageLoad again and never fires the Sorting event.

Any guides on how I do GridView sorting without AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery there is a plug-in:  http://tablesorter.com

Comment: Thanks the the link, I will save it!

Due to my odd list of requirements, I have to work within very specific versions of .net without use of AJAX or JQuery.

I did manage to find a solution though :) thanks anyway!